# "Can not write to queue directory" error and other sendmail issues after updating linode from Debian 8 to Stable

Tags: debian, sendmail, upgrade

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.linode.com/docs/security/upgrading/upgrade-debian-to-the-newest-release/) to upgrade my linode instance from Debian 8 to Stable.  In the wake of that upgrade, I've had several errors/issues with sendmail.

1. `$ which sendmail` doesn't return anything.  I *do* have sendmail installed.  It's at `/usr/sbin/sendmail`.
2. Sendmail's permissions are as follows:

   `$ ls -la /usr/sbin/sendmail
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jul 17 12:41 /usr/sbin/sendmail -> /etc/alternatives/sendmail`

   The link (`/etc/alternatives/sendmail`) is highlighted in red.
3. When I try to send a test email with `sudo echo "Subject: sendmail test" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v me@address.com` I get the following error:

   `can not write to queue directory /var/spool/mqueue-client/ (RunAsGid=115, required=0): Permission denied`

   *That* directory's permissions are:

   `$ ls -la /var/spool/mqueue-client
   drwxrwxr-x  2 root        root        4096 Sep 15  2018 mqueue-client`

So, I obviously have some sort of permission/ownership issue, but I also think there's something else going on given items 1 and 2.  I need to be able to receive emails from the system's OSSEC and Fail2ban, so I can't really go without a working email client/server.  I'm just not sure how to fix these issues.

My sendmail was simply installed with `$ sudo apt-get install sendmail sendmail-bin`, so it came direct from Debian's repos, which is why I'm a bit baffled by these issues... I assumed that whatever configuration was needed would be handled by the installation process.

EDIT: the output of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/sendmail*`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail -> /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail.8.gz -> /usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.sendmail.8.gz

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail-msp -> /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail-msp.8.gz -> /usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.sendmail.8.gz

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail-mta -> /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jul 17 12:41 /etc/alternatives/sendmail-mta.8.gz -> /usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.sendmail.8.gz
```

Each pair ends in a different color, e.g. `/usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail` is highlighted in amber, while `/usr/share/man/man8/sendmail.sendmail.8.gz` is highlighted in red.  It's the same colors - amber and red - for each pair.

EDIT2: The output of `(echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -d44.4 -i -v username` (I used my real username, but have adjusted the resulting output for security):

```
$ (echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -d44.4 -i -v username
safefile(/etc/mail/submit.cf, uid=1000, gid=0, flags=6000, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=1000, gid=0, flags=6000, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 4]   OK
safefile(/etc/mail/relay-domains, uid=1000, gid=0, flags=6580, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=1000, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    No such file or directory
safefile(/etc/mail/service.switch, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=6480, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 4]   OK
safefile(/etc/mail/service.switch, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=6480, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 4]   OK
safefile( , uid=1000, gid=115, flags=40, mode=660):
safedirpath(., uid=1000, gid=115, flags=40, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir .] OK
    No such file or directory
    [final dir . uid 111 mode 42770] Success
safedirpath(/var/spool/mqueue-client, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=0, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/spool/mqueue-client] OK
safefile(./dfx6MIGnM5005502, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2040, mode=600):
safedirpath(., uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2040, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir .] OK
    No such file or directory
    [final dir . uid 111 mode 42770] Success
username... Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
220 major-productions.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.15.2/8.15.2/Debian-12; Mon, 22 Jul 2019 14:16:49 -0400; (No UCE/UBE) logging access from: localhost(OK)-localhost [127.0.0.1]
>>> EHLO major-productions.com
250-major-productions.com Hello localhost [127.0.0.1], pleased to meet you
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-EXPN
250-VERB
250-8BITMIME
250-SIZE
250-DSN
250-ETRN
250-AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5
250-DELIVERBY
250 HELP
>>> VERB
250 2.0.0 Verbose mode
>>> MAIL From:<username@major-productions.com> SIZE=20 AUTH=username@major-productions.com
250 2.1.0 <username@major-productions.com>... Sender ok
>>> RCPT To:<username@major-productions.com>
>>> DATA
250 2.1.5 <username@major-productions.com>... Recipient ok
354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
>>> .
421 4.3.0 collect: Cannot write ./dfx6MIGnHm005503 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory
>>> QUIT
username... Deferred: 421 4.3.0 collect: Cannot write ./dfx6MIGnHm005503 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory
safefile(/var/lib/sendmail/sm-client.st, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2282, mode=600):
safedirpath(/var/lib/sendmail, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2282, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/lib/sendmail] OK
    No such file or directory
safefile(/var/lib/sendmail/sm-client.st, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2282, mode=600):
safedirpath(/var/lib/sendmail, uid=1000, gid=115, flags=2282, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/lib/sendmail] OK
    No such file or directory
Closing connection to [127.0.0.1]
```

EDIT 3: the output of `(echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -d44.4 -i -v username` while logged in as root (with the username obfuscated as before):

```
# (echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -d44.4 -i -v username
safefile(/etc/mail/sendmail.cf, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6000, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6000, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 400]     OK
safefile(/etc/mail/local-host-names, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 400]     OK
safefile(/etc/mail/relay-domains, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    No such file or directory
safefile(/etc/mail/service.switch, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6480, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 400]     OK
safefile(/etc/mail/service.switch, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6480, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 400]     OK
safedirpath(/var/spool/mqueue, uid=0, gid=0, flags=4, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/spool/mqueue] OK
safefile(/etc/mail/service.switch, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6480, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=6580, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 100644, mode 400]     OK
safefile(/etc/mail/aliases.db, uid=0, gid=0, flags=584, mode=400):
safedirpath(/etc/mail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=584, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /etc/mail] OK
    [uid 110, nlink 1, stat 100640, mode 400]   OK
safedirpath(/home/username, uid=1000, gid=1000, flags=1985, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /home/username] OK
safefile(/home/username/.forward.major-productions, uid=1000, gid=1000, flags=1895, mode=400):
    No such file or directory
safedirpath(/home/username, uid=1000, gid=1000, flags=1985, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /home/username] OK
safefile(/home/username/.forward, uid=1000, gid=1000, flags=1895, mode=400):
    No such file or directory
safefile(./dfx6MKLN6r006080, uid=0, gid=0, flags=2040, mode=600):
safedirpath(., uid=0, gid=0, flags=2040, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir .] OK
    No such file or directory
    [final dir . uid 0 mode 40700] Success
username... Connecting to local...
safefile(/usr/sbin/sensible-mda, uid=0, gid=0, flags=41904, mode=0):
safedirpath(/usr/sbin, uid=0, gid=0, flags=41904, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /usr/sbin] OK
    [uid 0, nlink 1, stat 104755, mode 0]   OK
username... Sent
safefile(/var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st, uid=0, gid=0, flags=2282, mode=600):
safedirpath(/var/lib/sendmail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=2282, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/lib/sendmail] OK
    No such file or directory
safefile(/var/lib/sendmail/sendmail.st, uid=0, gid=0, flags=2282, mode=600):
safedirpath(/var/lib/sendmail, uid=0, gid=0, flags=2282, level=0, offset=0):
    [dir /var/lib/sendmail] OK
    No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use `ls --dereference -l /usr/sbin/sendmail` to chase the soft links chain to the end.

Comment: I get the following: `-r-sr-sr-t 1 root smmsp 860672 Sep 15  2018 /usr/sbin/sendmail`, with the `/usr/sbin/sendmail` portion highlighted in red

Comment: Post info about results of `ls -l /etc/alternatives/sendmail*`

Comment: I've added it as an edit to the bottom of this question in order for the formatting to work

Comment: FYI, as of July 6, Debian stable is version 10 (buster), not version 9 (stretch). If you upgraded directly from version 8 to version 10, without an intermediate upgrade to version 9, then I strongly suspect that may be the source of your problem. Skipping major versions is officially not supported (or recommended).

Comment: I really wish the Linode tutorial said that....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `$ which sendmail` doesn't return anything.

`sendmail` **IS NOT** installed in non privileged users' `PATH` => you observe expected/normal result.
`sendmail` is expected to be executed by other programs like `mail` which use full/absolute path.

3. can not write to queue directory /var/spool/mqueue-client/ (RunAsGid=115, required=0): Permission denied

fix `/var/spool/mqueue-client` permissions and ownership

```
chown smmsp:smmsp /var/spool/mqueue-client`   
chmod 02770 /var/spool/mqueue-client`
```

**MODERN SENDMAIL DOES NOT REQUIRE TO BE SET INSTALLED AS `SET ROOT ID`**

see results of `ls -l --dereference /usr/sbin/sendmail` in the question's comments:
`-r-sr-sr-t 1 root smmsp 860672 Sep 15 2018 /usr/sbin/sendmail`

Change permission of the final target of `/usr/sbin/sendmail` and `/etc/alternatives` links in Debian:

```
chmod u-s /usr/lib/sm.bin/sendmail
```

Comment: I think I'm getting closer.  There are no errors on the command line, but looking at `/var/log/mail.log` I see repeated errors with `SYSERR(root): collect: Cannot write ./dfx6K1Vxg0016309 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory`

Comment: @MajorProductions I added one more fix to the answear

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying (long, hot weekend), but the error persists: `Jul 22 13:34:53 picus sm-mta[5208]: x6MHYrvA005208: SYSERR(root): collect: Cannot write ./dfx6MHYrvA005208 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory`

Comment: @MajorProductions As non-root execute the following test/diagnostic command `(echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -d44.4 -i -v username`.  sendmail may refuse to act when permissions are TOO BROAD (as security measure).

Comment: Hmm... the same error with the same hashed file name is in the output, but there are several other "No such file or directory" mentions in the output as well.  I'm going to post the output in my initial question for space/formatting

Comment: I've added the output to my question

Comment: It seems that the problem is in sendmail-MTA, not in sendmail-MSP. **As root** execute the following test/diagnostic command (echo subject: test; echo ; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -Am -d44.4 -i -v username

Comment: I've added the output to the bottom of my question

Comment: Any suggestions?  I really need to get this working ASAP

Comment: I've made some progress, but a slightly different problem has popped up.  Made a new question for it: https://serverfault.com/questions/976391/sendmail-error-cannot-mail-directly-to-files

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you run this:

`echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sudo sendmail /usr/sbin/sendmail -v me@address.com`

The distinction being that you are running echo as root, but not sendmail.

Thus the message: "(RunAsGid=115, required=0): Permission denied"

The "115" is the Group Id of your user, and it is expecting "0" (which is roots)

Comment: Same error, with the same Gid values.

Comment: My first comment was slightly off and did not include "sudo" in there. Did you pipe to `sudo sendmail`?

Comment: Yeah, same exact error/Gid values